# Windows Phone 8 SDK in VS2012, icons?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

Where can I change Icons for my App in VS2012 for Windows Phone 8?

How can I open WMAppManifest.xml in Visual Editor? Is it availble in Express edition?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Under the properties project folder, double click WMAppManifest.xml. It should be open up in it's own editor.

Edit: Right-Click WMAppManifest.xml and select View Designer.

Comment: Yes, it's opening, but in xml code. When I try to open it in Designer Mode it still opens in xml code. I don't know how to edit it.

Comment: As I remember there is no visual editor for MMAppManifest in VS Express

Comment: Yes, I click like You said, but it still opens in XML. Look at image above

Comment: Then you cannot do this in VS Express.

Comment: Is it 100% confirmed? Maybe there is some solution? How then change icon in project? I know where change 2 types of icons. But I would like to set wide tiled icon. Where can I do this?

Comment: Anton & Caleb - You definitely can do this in the Express version

Comment: Your schema may be screwed up in the file that you manually edited. Validate the XML and fix any errors, or generate a new WMAppManifest via another project and overwrite your previous one to get it working again. That is the only reason it wouldn't open.

Comment: Caleb have the right of it. And it's definitively possible in Express, as the Windows Phone division develops the SDK for Express initially, and later integrates it into the full VS package :)

Answer (score 1):

If you open `WMAppManifest.xml` file  in xml editor you can find this line:

```
<IconPath IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">ApplicationIcon.png</IconPath>
```

This is a path to application icon. Just change it.

Answer (score 1):

The visual designer is available in VS2012Express.

If "View Designer" isn't opening it with the designer, try right clicking on it, selecting "Open With" and then choose "Windows Phone Manifest Designer".
If that option doesn't work or is missing it would suggest a problem with the install. The first step in trying to address this would be to repair the install of the SDK.